# Encrypt/decrypt audio files in flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, audio

I am building an audio player that downloads and plays audio files using flutter. The audio files must be kept secure from piracy. I tried to encrypt the downloaded files and decrypt them when the user asks to play. I wanted to delete the decrypted data when the app is closed but when I delete the file the background music player crashes.
Is there any standard way to achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say without more informations (about the plugin you're using to play audio for example).

I'll take the case of AudioService.

AudioService work with a list of audio. Maybe you can try to empty this list before delete the decrypted data?

In your case, I think that your player try to read your audio after you delete it. The error may come from that point.

Comment: Yes I am using audio_service for the background playing task and just_audio as the audio player. The problem is if I don't delete the decrypted audio file when users leave the app(audio still playing in background) users can access the decrypted audio file which they can copy. I don't want the users to have access to the decrypted audio file. How can I achieve that?